# How to delete all files & directories in a directory including hidden ones except .htaccess?

Tags: linux, rm

As the question suggests, I have a situation where I have a folder that users can upload weird stuff there. Have a cron job set up to clean this folder every a few hours.

It has a .htaccess for security reasons, of course, my question is, how can I delete everything (files and directories) in that directory, including hidden ones whose name start with a dot, but not the **.htaccess**?

I currently have `rm -rf *` to do the job but if the user uploads a file with a name starting with a dot, it would not be deleted.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you copy the `.htaccess` to a new directory, remove the whole directory at once, then rename the directory back?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What do you mean by renaming the directory back? I thought it's removed? Wouldn't this approach temporarily disable the uploading feature?

Comment: he means something like `mkdir newDir; cp uploadDir/.haccess newDir; rmdir uploadDir; mv newDir uploadDir;`

Comment: The method above will stop uploads for the tiny amount of time the folder doesn't exist. Ingacio's answer works and keeps the directory intact.

Comment: It will also interfere with external tools such as SELinux that depend on certain properties of the directory itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob
rm !(.htaccess)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the options dotglob and extglob permanently set thereafter or are they just temporary? Am I supposed to disable them after this?

Comment: They're set until you disable them. If you want them temporarily set then run the commands in a subshell.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use find, like: `find /path/to/dir/ -mindepth 1 -not -name .htaccess -delete`